# using the form module in python django

Tags: python, django, forms

In Django there is a form module and inside there is a FORM class

```
from django import forms

class myform(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField()
```

But if I did:

```
from django.forms import Form

class myForm(Form):
    name = ??
```

My question is if Form is the class inside the module form and we are inheriting from it then
while creating forms why we have to explicitly call   `forms.charField()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its 'coz CharField class exists in forms.fields, so you have to import forms to write something like forms.CharField.You can also write this:`from django.forms.fields import CharField`
Take a look at this file https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py

Answer (score 0):

All the form fields in django are subclasses of ***django.forms.fields.***

**Note-: that django.forms.fields.**

In order to access a particular field you need to have access to django.forms module.Form class which is at heart of django FORM api is in parallel to these classes in the same module and is as django.forms.Form.

Comment for more explanations cheers :-)